# Etymology of close |kləʊz| (klōz) & close |kləʊs| (klōs)

Tags: etymology, differences

In doing research for the question *[Is it “close-minded” or “closed-minded”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28956/5822)*, which was in turn prompted by the discussion under [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28866/what-to-call-a-person-who-doesnt-want-to-learn-anything-new/28868#28868) to another question, I realized that some of the confusion around the word *close* had to do with its versatility (it can be an adverb, adjective, noun or verb).

We have two primary pronunciations of *close* (klōz and klōs) that help us distinguish how the word is being used. I thought at first that this was fairly straightforward. When the 'z' sound is used, it is usually a verb:

> I *close* the door.

The 'z' ending is also used in the following noun form:

> I'll bring my argument to a *close*.

When the 's' ending is used, it is usually either an adjective in these ways,

> The hotel is *close* to the sea.
>   My brother and I are very *close*.

or an adverb in these ways:

> Please sit *close* to me.
>   I'll keep  your secret *close*.

But as I read through the lengthy entries on *close* in my *New Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*, things started to get confusing. I found *close* (klōs) listed as a noun meaning *a closed place* and *close* (klōs) also listed as an adjective meaning *closed, shut* as well as *secretive*, *stingy*, and *hidden*.

**Questions**:

1. How and when did the different uses
   of *close* take on different
   pronunciations?
2. Are *close* (klōs)
   as a noun and *close* (klōs) =
   *closed* familiar to others?
3. If these rarer uses of *close*
   (klōs)
       were once common, when and why did
       they fall out of favor?
4. Etymologically, what overlap exists
       between *close* (klōs) = *near* and *close* (klōz) =
       *shut*?

Comment: I'm getting [Semantic Satiation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-the-feeling-you-get-after-looking-at-a-word-for-too)...

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's work from the basics on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=close). All senses of the word derive ultimately from Latin *clausus*, the past participle of the verb *claudere*. The verb form made its way to English from the past participle stem *clos-* of Old French *clore* /klor/, to *shut* or *cut off from*. The adjective form meaning *strictly confined* or *secret* is from the related Old French *clos*, and while /s/ is usually voiced in French, Old French had unvoiced final consonants.

So that was the original source of the difference, and it stuck and developed over time. The adjectival meaning of *near* is from the 15th century, by way of *closing a gap*.

Answer (score 2):

1. They always had different pronunciations.  Verb *close* (which the noun was derived from) used to have the "e" pronounced, which caused the voicing of the "s", while adjective *close* never did — the "e" was only to indicate the long vowel.
2. From glancing at the OED, this meaning appears to be used in the English Midlands and maybe Scotland (though to what extent I don't know).  I think this would be unfamiliar to most Americans at least.
3. I'm not sure that it was ever particularly common, or that there is an answer for why it isn't used more.
4. Both of these words came from the same Latin root, but were borrowed into English at different times.  Verb *close* came from Latin *claud-ĕre* via the Old French present subjunctive stem (*clos-*), first cited in 1275.  The adjective *close* came from Latin *claus-um*, past participle of *claud-ĕre*, via French *clos*, first cited around 1400.