# What is the Pronunciation of "-sts" at the end of the word?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

How can we pronounce words ending with -**sts**?

- lists
- costs
- tests

I often heard people pronunce its like,

- lɪsts and kɒsts
- lɪsː kɔsː

but which one is acceptable?

Comment: What in the world does “more appropriate” mean in this context?  Isn’t that yet another trendy euphemism for “better”, like “inappropriate behaviour” is just a trendy euphemism for “wrong behaviour”, “bad behaviour”, or quite simply “misbehaviour”? It’s as though someone were getting paid by the letter, not the idea. Does your “more appropriate pronunciation” here mean ***right/wrong, good/bad, common/rare, accceptable/unacceptable, standard/nonstandard, courteous/rude, respectable/risible,*** or what? Inquiring minds want to know. ☺

Comment: @tchrist,What are you coming to say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In rapid speech particularly, consonants in clusters such as /sts/ are frequently lost in a process known to phoneticians as ‘elision’. Similarly, ‘next’ will occur as /neks/ and ‘acts’ as /aks/. It’s not so much a matter of bad pronunciation as a recognized feature of speech which most of us will display at one time or another.

Comment: I suspect there may be a difference between U.S. and Commonwealth speech here. I never reduce words like lists to -/sː/, nor do I notice other Americans doing so; but I do notice one of my relatives (British-educated) saying things I hear as "lissss".

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Have you ever had your spontaneous speech recorded?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the conversation, over a bad phone line.

> Alice: Let's talk about the kɒsː associated with with this project
>
> Bob: I'm sorry, "Coss"?
>
> Alice: No. kɒsts. C.O.S.T.S.
>
> Bob: Ah, sorry, you were speaking too quickly.

These are simple words that are said as they are written -- nothing to catch us out as with trough and plough.

But in English, as I believe with almost every language, people tend to rush over words. This is how *going to* becomes *gonna*.

So, it's *kɒsts* and *lɪsts*, when spoken by the Queen or a newsreader, but the *t* might disappear in everyday conversation.

Comment: Final consonant clusters are normally reduced in English speech. Nobody ever says /fayv sɪksθs/ for _5/6;_ the /θ/ disappears and you just get a long /s/ - /fayv sɪks:/. You can hear the difference between this and the sequence _5, 6_ in the pronunciation of any unmonitored native speaker.

Comment: I think you’ve written /y/ when you meant /j/.

Comment: @tchrist, y is used in [Americanist transcription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americanist_phonetic_notation#Vocalics)

Comment: @nohat ♦ I’ve never seen that before. What’s that, APA then? If it’s provincial, does that mean it’s anti-IPA? How is that useful? I didn’t realize this was an Americanist place. Wouldn’t it be better to use the international standard? Or if one couldn’t be bothered, to actually say what was using?  In my experience, that sort of notation is ***ALWAYS*** IPA.

Comment: @tchrist I think at one point there was some kind of academic battle of IPA vs. Americanist, but these days IPA is pretty much universal, with the exception that there is some historical holdover of informal transcriptions of English using some Americanist traditions that more closely parallel English spelling (like using the symbol y for (IPA) [j]).

Comment: @tchrist this isn't "an Americanist place" insomuch as it's a place where people use whatever transcriptions they're most comfortable with.

Comment: Finally, I think it is pertinent to note that /y/ for this sound pretty much matches how every American and many British dictionaries transcribe English, as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonetic_alphabet

Comment: One last thing is that if Mr. Lawler had indeed used standard IPA to transcribe the word *five* above, he would have substituted [ɪ] for [y], not [j].

Answer (score 2):

The accepted pronunciation of '-sps', '-sts', and '-sks' is to drop the stop, and the 's' may or may not be extended (as though it were a doubled s). It is not frowned upon at all to not pronounce the p, t, k, even in slower speech.

In expected-articulate speech, say newscasters and actors, there will be a tendency to not drop.

Answer (score 0):

*lɪsts* and *kɒsts* definitely. The others are just bad pronunciation.

Comment: Different people pronounce things differently, whether others like it or not. Pronunciation is **oral**, not moral.