# What does "somebody plays things close to the vest" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I heard this phrase in the "Pirates of the Caribbean" and also found it online by googling it.

What does the phrase mean?

Comment: Related question: [is it close to the chest or close to the vest](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/is-it-close-to-the-chest-or-close-to-the-vest).

Comment: FYI, a somewhat similar interesting phrase is "so that .. the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that a person keeps their motivations a secret.  It comes from poker: you hold your cards close to your "vest" or body so you don't "tip your hand" or accidentally allow the other players to see your cards.

[This is a really nice article](http://web.archive.org/web/20070217165037/http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000825) about the phrase, and includes some related poker phrases.

Note: The linked article is The Maven's Word of the Day from August 25, 2000. This series of articles was published by Random House between 1996 to 2001.  I cannot find an online archive (other than the Wayback), although I will continue to look.

Comment: It's very interesting that a surprisingly large number of common phrases come from card games.  I'm holding all the aces, etc etc etc.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy Thanks for letting me know. I linked it through the Wayback Machine so that people could read it, but I am also searching for a better link.

Answer (score 0):

The Wayback Machine hung for me, but their "Getting Impatient" link worked just fine.

Incidentally, the article ends by mentioning several poker-based idioms (e.g., *lay your cards on the table*, *wear your poker face*, etc.).  Conspicuously absent, though, was the term "*all-in*," which seems to have gained traction more recently (the article is more than a decade old now).  Still this emphasizes how poker-inspired idioms are STILL making their way into everyday speech.