# Close to the Chest or Vest. What does it mean?

Tags: idiom-requests

Hi fellow language enthusiasts, so what does "Close to the Vest" or "Chest" mean may I ask? Or more appropriately "Chest" or "Vest" because I also learn that Chest appeared First. But what does the phrase mean at all? Any help is eagerly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "somebody plays things close to the vest" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/what-does-somebody-plays-things-close-to-the-vest-mean)

Answer (score 7):

*[Keep/hold your cards close to one's chest/vest](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+cards+close+to+vest)* means *keep your intended actions secret* (as if one were playing a card game).

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is an idiom for keeping something that is sensitive to you personal and not readily available to anyone but the few that you trust.

Example:

> Jonny's struggle with his uprising addiction to cocaine was a matter he kept close to his chest.